# default website is not reachable on an EC2 instance

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, iis, windows-server-2016, website

I have created an EC2 instance using windows 2016 datacenter image.
Once I rdp to that server, I have installed IIS and tried to browse to default website on that server (not externally). I am getting following error

"This page can’t be displayed
•Make sure the web address is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes."

I have made sure that firewall for port#80 is open.
Any ideas on what else I can try or what could causing the issue?

I have created another ticket for jenkins here for the same server. The reason I created this request, as I wanted to keep the questions clean. (https://superuser.com/questions/1513804/installed-jenkins-on-windows-ec2-instance?noredirect=1#comment2290648_1513804)

Comment: What is the URL in your browser address bar? As you have installed other software (Jenkins for instance), they can simply take over port 80 from IIS, so if you really want to test IIS, use a really clean machine.

Comment: It's usually the windows firewall or a security group.

Comment: Installed Jenkins to use default port of 8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed IE Enhanced Security to Off for Administrators to browse. In the long run, I will change the Group policy to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you should edit the security group and you should enable access you your ip from anywhere and open port 80 tcp in security group